# Issue after creating a docker image

Tags: rust

I got success in creating the docker image but in step 4 I got this message

[docker image message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6p7J.png)

after mentioning docker image command I am getting the message

[docker image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1wG7.png)

and when I tried to run my code I am getting nothing

[running command in cmd for particular image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7487L.png)

How to resolve this issue

This is inside dockerfile

```
FROM rust:1.36.0 

COPY Cargo.lock app/Cargo.lock

COPY Cargo.toml app/Cargo.toml

RUN mkdir syedghufranhassan\piaic\projects\rustredis\src\

RUN echo 'fn main() { use std::net::TcpListener; 

TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:6379").unwrap(); println!("Connection established"); }'> \Users\syedghufranhassan\piaic\projects\rustredis\src\main.rs
```

Comment: Downvoting because text is posted as image.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is resolved. I create Dockerfile with following commands below

```
FROM rust:1.36.0 
COPY Cargo.lock /app/Cargo.lock 
COPY Cargo.toml /app/Cargo.toml 
COPY main.rs /app/main.rs 
WORKDIR /app
RUN echo 'fn main() { use std::net::TcpListener; 
TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:6379").unwrap(); println!("Connection established"); }'> 
/app/main.rs 
CMD cargo run app/main.rs
```

Prior to creating Dockerfile I placed following code below [PACKAGE] and above [DEPENDENCIES] in Cargo.TOML file

```
[[bin]]
name = "main"
path = "/app/main.rs"
```

So Now the docker image is running successfully.

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify nothing to run within the container. I suppose you want to run the code inside your rust file, which you are creating in the last two lines. A correct approach would be to COPY the rust file within the container and run it using CMD.
So, your Dockerfile should look something like:

```
FROM rust:1.36.0 

COPY Cargo.lock app/Cargo.lock

COPY Cargo.toml app/Cargo.toml

#COPY YOUR RUST APP ON THE CONTAINER
COPY main.rs app/main.rs

RUN mkdir syedghufranhassan\piaic\projects\rustredis\src\

RUN echo 'fn main() { use std::net::TcpListener; 

#RUN YOUR APP USING YOUR APPROPRIATE ARGUMENTS
CMD [ "rust", "app/main.rs" ]
```

Comment: Thank you for responding but now I am getting this error. Can you help me please in resolving the issue

docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"rust\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

Comment: Now I again rectified by following:

FROM rust:1.36.0 
COPY Cargo.lock app/Cargo.lock
COPY Cargo.toml app/Cargo.toml
COPY main.rs app/main.rs
RUN mkdir /src
RUN echo 'fn main() { use std::net::TcpListener; TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:6379").unwrap(); println!("Connection established"); }'> /src/main.rs
WORKDIR /src

but now after running the docker image I am not getting any ouput now.